# xcode, ios, Can't move buttons around screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, button

The Output on Console:

> 2015-07-02 17:31:49.105 Make Maths Fun[15079:90b] but_1.center.x =
>   155.000000 but_1.center.y = 90.000000
>
> 2015-07-02 17:31:49.105 Make Maths Fun[15079:90b] but_2.center.x =
>   155.000000 but_2.center.y = 140.000000

The Code:

```
but_1.center = CGPointMake(155, 90);
but_2.center = CGPointMake(155, 140);
```

Screenshot:

[image]

The Output says that it is at that x and y but when I run the program they are where I had them on the `viewcontroller`

Comment: are there any autolayout constraints on the buttons? are they in different UIView containers?

Comment: try to put border and color and check what is the issue. check whether they are at correct position or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

Disable your Use Auto Layout option and then try again.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using AutoLayouts then setting the postion of button from code do not work. So you have two options

1. Disable the Autolayouts from story board and then set the
   position from code.
2. If you using autoLayouts then you have to make the IBOutlet of
   constraint, you can use anyone Leading Space Constraint of Trailing
   space constraint outlet. And then set the constant of that
   constraint (the constraint of which you make IBOutlet) at the run
   time from code to get desired position.